# Database SQL Select Distinct

Tags: sql, database, distinct

I need to show all information from all columns in the table, but filter so that all records that occurred in the duplicate email will be discarded one and keep the other one so that there is no duplication.

Example before the filter:

```
Name 1 | City 1 | Email 1
Name 2 | City 2 | Email 2
Name 3 | City 3 | Email 1
```

After the filter should display as follows:

```
Name 1 | City 1 | Email 1
Name 2 | City 2 | Email 2
```

Record 3 was disregarded because it has the same e-mail (duplicate) as record 1.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by email order by email) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: It wouldn't be exactly that, I want to remove all duplicates from the E-MAIL column, the final result must contain all the columns of the table respecting the duplicity filter.

Comment: @crishenrique1986 . . . This returns one row per email with all the columns in one of the rows.  Isn't that what you want?